# Testing react-router Redirects with Jest and Enzyme

Tags: reactjs, redirect, react-router, jestjs, enzyme

I have a simple React component using react-router which redirects the user if they don't have permission to view a certain route:

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {permission: false};
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/users">
          <h2>A list of users</h2>
        </Route>
        <Route path="/users/:userId">
          {({match}) => this.state.permission ? <h1>{match.params.userId}</h1> : <Redirect to="/users" />}
        </Route>
      </Switch>
    );
  }
}
```

I am trying to test the different scenarios when accessing `/users/:userId` using Jest and Enzyme, but am unable to get the test to succeed when the user has permission.

My tests are as follows:

```
describe("render()", () => {
  describe("when route is /users/:userId", () => {
    let wrapper;
    let app;
    beforeEach(() => {
      wrapper = mount(
        <MemoryRouter initialEntries={["/users/1"]}>
          <App />
        </MemoryRouter>
      );
      app = wrapper.find(App).instance();
    });

    describe("when user has permission", () => {
      beforeEach(() => {
        app.setState({permission: true});
      });

      it("should show users id", () => {
        expect(wrapper.exists("h1")).toBe(true);
      });
    });

    describe("when user doesn't have permission", () => {
      beforeEach(() => {
        app.setState({permission: false});
      });

      it("should redirect to users list", () => {
        expect(wrapper.exists("h2")).toBe(true);
      });
    });
  });
});
```

The first test fails while the second succeeds. I've used `console.log(wrapper.debug());` in the first test and it shows that the component is rendering the first route (i.e. being redirected) and I've printed out the state so I can see that the `setState` call is working.

How should I rewrite my tests to make this work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Issue

The initial location is set to `/users/1` but when the component first mounts it renders the `Redirect` which sets the location to `/users`.

`permission` is then set to `true` but since location is `/users` the result is `<h2>A list of users</h2>`.

---

### Solution

After setting `permission` to `true`, set the location to `/users/1` so the location is correct and the test successfully renders `<h1>1</h1>`:

```jsx
describe("render()", () => {
  describe("when route is /users/:userId", () => {
    let wrapper;
    let app;
    beforeEach(() => {
      wrapper = mount(
        <MemoryRouter initialEntries={["/users/1"]}>
          <App />
        </MemoryRouter>
      ); // the Redirect sets location to /users during the initial render
      app = wrapper.find(App).instance();
    });

    describe("when user has permission", () => {
      beforeEach(() => {
        app.setState({permission: true});
        wrapper.instance().history.replace('/users/1'); // replace the MemoryRouter location with /users/1
        wrapper.update(); // update the wrapper with the changes
      });

      it("should show users id", () => {
        expect(wrapper.exists("h1")).toBe(true); // SUCCESS
      });
    });

    describe("when user doesn't have permission", () => {
      beforeEach(() => {
        app.setState({permission: false});
      });

      it("should redirect to users list", () => {
        expect(wrapper.exists("h2")).toBe(true);
      });
    });
  });
});
```